# eclipse linking errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

In trying to compile a cpp program using eclipse. I am running into the following linking error.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
undefined reference to `gsl_isnan'  mrconvert       line 453, external location: C:\mrtrix\source\mrtrix-0.2.11\lib\mrtrix.h    C/C++ Problem
```

Firstly, I am not sure exactly how to located all the libraries which are required. Help in this regard much appreciated.

However, when I do try to add a library to eclipse eg C:\GnuWin32\lib\libgsl
"Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Libraries. Under GNU C++ Clicking Add, then File System and putting in the path to the files. "

I get this error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cannot find -lC:/GnuWin32/lib/libgsl    mrconvert           C/C++ Problem
```

How do I properly link to libraries in eclipse?

Much appreciated
Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove "lib" and ".a" from your library name:
Use "gsl" instead "libgsl.a"

And remove the full library path "C:/GnuWin32/lib/".
Use "-LC:/GnuWin32/lib/", setting up it from linker library settings.

[image]

Check that library "libgsl.a" is located in the specified path.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Cesar, didnt realize the path and the actual library had to be separated